# Removing window when clicked on close?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, delegates, nswindow

I have created a MAAttached window like this -

```
attachedWindow = MAAttachedWindow(view: castedView.view, attachedToPoint: point, inWindow: self.view.window!, onSide: MAPositionBottom , atDistance: 5.0)
attachedWindow!.delegate = self
attachedWindow!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

and I have used NSWindowDelegate for-

```
        func windowDidResignKey(notification: NSNotification) {
        attachedWindow!.orderOut(self)
}
```

This works well when I click anywhere other than attachedWindow, but when I click on standard close, miniaturise, zoom button of window just below this attachedWindow, then **windowDidResignKey** is not called. So the attachedWindow is not removed, and stays there on screen. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't click on standard close, miniaturise, zoom should call **windowDidResignKey**?